# Get CGImageRef from CCSprite, CCTexture2D or even directly from CCSpriteFrameCache?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have written some code that takes a UIImage.CGImageRef and puts it into a context so that I can analyze it. This all works great. BUT, I now wish to implement this process in a Cocos2D app.

All of my graphics for the app are done as sprite sheets using Texture Packer so I am looking for any way to get the CGImageRef that I require out of the sprite sheet.

My theory is that you can init a CCSprite with a CGImageRef so why can't I simply get it back out again?

Maybe I am missing something simple like does Cocos2D have a CGImageRef equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try smth like this

```
    CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:size.width height:size.height];
    [renderer begin];

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [m_sprite batchNode];
    if (spriteSheet != nil) 
        [spriteSheet visit];
    else 
        [m_sprite visit];

    [renderer end];

    NSData* uidata = [renderer getUIImageAsDataFromBuffer:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
    UIImage* uiimage = [UIImage imageWithData:uidata];

    CGImageRef image = [uiimage CGImage];
```

Comment: I do like the sound of this but I can't seem to get it to work. It could be the way I am setting up the sprite sheet? I am using CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sheet.pvr.ccz"];

Answer (score 0):

You can get image data from OpenGL via `glReadPixels`. It needs some adjustments, but it would be wrong solution in performance aspect. OpenGL is designed as one-way conveyer (you pass data and don't read it back). Depending on your concrete task you may preload image data when loading textures from file.

As example we use alpha channel of textures for per-pixel touch test. So, when we load image we store its bitmask of alpha threshold in memory.

Answer (score 0):

no
cctexture direct from [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] read from photo file
ccspriteframe direct from [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] read from ".plist" file